# InitializeComponent in both constructors, or in one with constructor inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, initialization, components

Is there any practical difference in terms of effects on the component model between:

```
class MyComponent : Component {
    public MyComponent() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyComponent(IContainer container) {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and:

```
class MyComponent : Component {
    public MyComponent() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyComponent(IContainer container) : this() {
        container.Add(this);
    }
}
```

and if not, why did Microsoft pick the first method for their designer-generated code?

Edit: What I mean is, will there be any side effects towards the change of order between initializing the component and adding it to the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of execution differs. In

```
public MyComponent(IContainer container) {
    container.Add(this);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

`InitializeComponent()` is executed *after* `container.Add()`, whereas here

```
public MyComponent(IContainer container) : this() {
    container.Add(this);
}
```

`container.Add()` is executed after `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: But does this make any difference in terms of effects on the component model? I probably should have been more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order of invocation will be different between the two. I believe in the second one, this() is called first, then the contents of the method. This means InitializeComponent() will be called before container.Add.

While that may not make a huge difference, it is a difference nonetheless.